# Directly read bytes produced by gcc

Tags: python, gcc, makefile, compilation

I have a python program that trigger a compilation through the command 'make' on the system.
I'd like to read directly the program built by gcc in the compilation process without having the binary writed to the disk,
Is that possible ?

thanks !

Comment: vague guess `gcc ... -o -|python script.py`? `-` is used by a lot of apps to signify "write to stdout"

Comment: You could set the destination to a ramdisk but you can't prevent gcc writing to a filesystem without changing the Makefile script.

Comment: I can change the makefile script and the python program but i don't know about ramdisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help:

```
gcc main.c -o /dev/stdout
```

Comment: of course it can be mixed with gcc -S main.c -o /dev/stdout